# how to hide OTHER form from current form C#

Tags: c#, forms, hide

I have two forms form1 and form2
I'm trying to hide my form1 from form2.
How to do it? 
I don't want to hide form1 unless I finish my process in form2. If i finish my process in form2 then my form1 will close/hide.

the code below doesn't work. . .

```
       Form1 Frm = new Form1();
       Frm.Hide();
```

or

```
       Form1 Frm = new Form1();
       Frm.Visible = false;
```

Comment: You should not create new form. Instead you should hide your existed `form1`. Supposing `form1` is variable pointing to the instance of form you need to hide, just do it like `form1.Hide()`.

Comment: Thanks for comment. how to hide it? if im in form2? I cannot directly put Form1.Hide();

Comment: Obviously, `Form1` is name of your form class. But have you any instance of that class (form itself) available in your `form2`? Code you've provided is insufficient to make an assumption on it. Can you show more relevant code?

Comment: Thanks :) I appreciate your help. I already answered my question. You can also close this question. Thanks @AndyKorneyev

Answer (score 0):

You should use Application.OpenForms collection, find your open form in there and call the .Hide() method on it.

Comment: Thank you very much. You can close this question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used this code and it works. Thanks @PedroLuz!

```
 var frm = Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().Where(x => x.Name == "Form1").FirstOrDefault();
                if (null != frm)
                {
                    frm.Hide();
                }
```